# How do I Transfer the Cell Data from one Column to the Hyperlink Address for a Corresponding Column's cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

How do I transfer the cell data from one column to the Hyperlink address for a corresponding column's cells in Excel 2010?

Example:

```
Cell F4: www.microsoft.com
Cell F5: www.google.com

Cell C4: Microsoft
Cell C5: Google
```

I would like to make the cells in Column C hyperlinks to the addresses listed in Column F.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the HYPERLINK formula :

Either in another column:

```
=HYPERLINK(F4,C4)
```

Either if your URL are all the same, you can use [Left, Right and Mid functions](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/save-time-by-using-excels-left-right-and-mid-string-functions/1033367).
Tell us if you need an example.

[EDIT : an example !]
Let's assume your URL begins with "www." and ends with a dot "." and several characters (assuming we don't know how many).

```
=HYPERLINK(F4,PROPER(MID(F4;5;LEN(F4)-SEARCH(".";F4;LEN(F4)-5)-1)))
```

My excel version is not in english so tell me if it does not work. At least, i hope it will give you some clues on how to manage it.

Btw, some caveats :

- domain names cannot be longer than 4
  char (cf. LEN(B1) - 5 part of the formula)
- if there are some dots inside the name, they will remain and the PROPER formula will upper the case --> this can be treated by a REPLACE formula

Hope that will help,

Regards,

Max

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer! Can you give me an example?

Comment: Also, for row C with the Data, how can I add the =Hyperlink formula without replacing the actual text?

Comment: You'd better use another column with the formula. You can even hide the column C afterwards

Comment: Thank you. When I create the new column, how can I have the formula generate the inputs automatically? So, =Hyperlink (F4,E4) (F5,E5) etc.

Comment: not sure i understood your question but i'll give it a try : you can enter the formula in a new cell (let's say on G4) : *=HYPERLINK(F4,C4)* and then, you only have to drag it down (http://www.handyexceltips.com/2008/01/16/dragging-a-formula-down/) to the end of you data. If it does not answer your question, feel free to let me know